# Do Temple Run 2 artifacts (masks, rings, and holidays) appear randomly, or based on your actions?

Tags: temple-run-2

Do chests appear randomly, or are they rewarded after you achieve specific things?  What achievements?  The odd distribution (I've gotten 8 Fire Breather masks, and only one of most of them) hints that it isn't random.

- The ten rings are Infinite Loop, Angel Wings, Twisted Root, Floating
  Island, Sky Clasp, Demon Claw, Ruby Shard, Caves Maw, Mystic Rocks,
  and Idol's Curse.
- The ten masks are Fire Breather, Infinite Seeker, Traveling Tiki,
  Skyward Scream, Serpent's Smile, Silent Menace, Jade Monster, The
  Gatekeeper, Demon Skull, and Face of the Idol
- The five Christmas artifacts are Candy Cane, Stocking, Holly,
  Present, and Wreath.

Also, have you ever opened *more than one* chest per run?  I ask because all this work to reach Level 10 is making me kill myself after I grab a chest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked support@imangistudios.com the question, and here is their answer.

> Chests are indeed random. You can only get one per run.

Comment: They do seem to be biased towards limited-time artifacts while they're in season, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some information to reconcile the other answers, which appear to be in conflict:

1. You can only grab one chest per run
2. Chests will continue to appear until you have successfully grabbed a chest

That is, if you do not successfully jump to grab a chest, other chests may still appear.  If you miss those chests also, they may continue to appear.  But once you jump and get a chest, no more will appear that run.

So if you are trying to accumulate artifacts, you may consider intentionally dying after grabbing a chest and then starting a fresh run to get another chance at an artifact.  On the other hand, for a long, high-scoring run, once you grab a chest, you can continue knowing that the future power ups are now more likely to be useful ones (boost, coin magnet, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** get more in one run.

I know this for a fact because I got sky clasp in the beginning of a run, then ran for another 38,000 meters, and got no more. But, if you miss the artifact it will show up again.

Comment: This is a poor line of reasoning. Source: I just ran 46000 until I saw my first artifact, and frequently don't see one until about 30000.

Answer (score 0):

I have got more than one chest in a run.  The masks, and all other prizes in the chests, are completely random.  Unfortunately, they don't do anything.  Except the Christmas prizes let you wear a santa hat.  Woo-pee.